# What are non-banking financial companies?

Tags: india, banking, financial-literacy

I read in the book *Indian Economy* by Ramesh Singh that,

> NBFCs are fast emerging as an important segment of Indian financial system. It is an heterogeneous group of institutions performing financial intermediation in a variety of ways, like accepting deposits, making loans and advances, leasing and hire purchase etc.

I am extremely unfamiliar with the financial terms. What does this mean?

Comment: Which terms specifically?

Comment: @glibdud "variety of ways, like accepting deposits, making loans and advances,leasing and hire purchase"

Comment: Reserve Bank of India: [FAQ: All you wanted to know about NBFCs](https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=92)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many countries there are companies that verge on the edge of being a bank, even though many people don't realize it.

- Casinos. They move massive amounts of money.
- Automobile companies. Their financing arm handles many loans
- The company that finances all those new smart phones that people pay for over 30 months.
- Companies that finance the purchases of large industrial equipment.
- Peer-to-peer lending companies

The list and regulations depends on the country.

Comment: What are Peer to Peer lending companies?

Comment: these are companies that facilitate small loans between people.

Comment: Why would somebody want to lend someone when his business involves so much risk?

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal That's why there is a higher interest rate on higher risk loans.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words,

Non-Banking Financial Companies also know as NBFCs are establishments that provide financial services and banking facilities without meeting the legal definition of a bank. They are covered under the Banking regulations laid down by the Reserve Bank of India and provide banking services like loans, credit facilities, TFCs, retirement planning, investing, and stocking in the money market. However, they are restricted from taking any form of deposits from the general public.